# Oracle APEX - how to refresh Interactive Grid after save process executes

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive grid that is updated via custom javascript when the user clicks the custom toolbar button. Then the result is saves using grid's `save` button via a process. After the process runs, the old data (present before the update) gets displayed until the grid is refreshed manually. My question is what is the best way to kick off the grid refresh manually after update process finishes?

Comment: I don't understand... are you saving your IG without do a direct change in your IG?
So you are executing a PL/SQL without submit the page? How? Anyway, there is a dynamic action event "Save [Interactive Grid]" that you can use to do something after a save action is executed in your IG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution by @Prashant_417 work successfully with me, but instead of refresh region i submit the page

0

I came across the same problem of refreshing the grid after click on SAVE.This is how it can be resolved.

Follow the steps below :

Create Dynamic Action
When → Custom
Custom Event → interactivegridsave (Do not change this)
Selection Type → Region
Region → your IG region
Now create a true action for the Dynamic Action.

Action → submit page
Please make sure the event name interactivegridsave is spelled correctly as the interactivegridsave fires after the execution of SAVE process.

thanks u

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem of refreshing the grid after click on **SAVE**.This is how it can be resolved.

Follow the steps below :

- Create Dynamic Action

  - When → Custom
  - Custom Event → interactivegridsave (Do not change this)
  - Selection Type → Region
  - Region → your IG region

Now create a true action for the Dynamic Action.

- Action → Refresh
- Selection Type → Region
- Region → your IG region

Please make sure the event name **interactivegridsave** is spelled correctly as the **interactivegridsave** fires after the execution of **SAVE** process.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1- Create an item, for example, P1_FLAG.

2- Create a dynamic action.

- Name: refresh_ig
- Event: Change
- Selection Type: Item(s)
- Item(s): P1_FLAG

In Client-side Condition:

- Type: Item = Value
- Value: 1

3- Create TRUE Action.

- Action: Refresh

Affected Elements

- Selection Type: Region
- Region: Your interactive grid region.

4- Create TRUE Action.

- Action: Set Value
- Set Type: PL/SQL Function Body
- PL/SQL Function Body: Return null;
- Items to Submit: P1_FLAG
- Selection type: Item(s)
- Item(s): P1_FLAG

Finally, in your process
  **:P1_FLAG := 1;**

Comment: did not work. The change DA for the P1_FLAG did not fire

Comment: The item take the value of 1?

Comment: In your interactive grid: go to source and set **Page Items to Submit** = P1_FLAG

Comment: still nothing happens

Comment: It really works for me, I have no idea that it may be failing. If you could share your application at [Oracle Apex](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex) I could take a look.